# openssl CAPI Engine dll not generating in openssl version 1.0.1x

Tags: openssl, openssl-engine

I am trying to use `capi engine` using windows certificate store.
openssl version used is `1.0.1x`.

Acc. to my knowledge for version `0.9.8`, CAPI engine is not compiled by default thus we have to use a switch `enable-capieng` to compile it and there is no engine dll generated so it will get built into `libeay32.dll`

But in `v1.0.1x`, i think `CAPI engine` is compiled by default and the engine dll i.e `capi.dll` is generated. But in my case it is not generated. So what could be possible reason for this ?
Should i have to use switch `enable-capieng` with this as well ?

Comment: Is ***`OPENSSL_NO_CAPIENG`*** defined in ***`opensslconf.h`***? Also see [Grep for CAPI](http://pastebin.com/r5V3aT8E) on Pastebin.

Comment: @jww :- when i am checking the availabiltiy of engine in openssl cmd line using cmd `engine capi -t`. It shows that capi is available.